# TelegramAPI MTProto checkPone do not responde

Tags: python, telegram, mtproto

I tried to implement telegram api with python.

base code forked form https://github.com/datamachine/twx

and I want to add checkPhone and sendCode feature, but server always returns result that cannot be understood.

here is my code

```
import os
import struct
from io import BytesIO
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from twx.mtproto.mtproto import MTProto as MTProtoParent, crc32
from twx.mtproto import rpc
from twx.mtproto import crypt
from hexdump import hexdump


class sendCode(rpc.TLObject):
    constructor = 0x768d5f4d

    def __init__(self, phone_number, sms_type, api_id, api_hash, lang_code):
        self.phone_number = phone_number  # bytes
        self.sms_type = sms_type  # integer
        self.api_id = int(api_id)  # integer
        self.api_hash = api_hash  # string
        self.lang_code = lang_code  # string

    def get_bytes(self):
        phone_number_io = BytesIO()
        rpc.serialize_string(phone_number_io, self.phone_number)

        params_io = BytesIO()
        rpc.serialize_string(params_io, self.api_hash.encode())
        rpc.serialize_string(params_io, self.lang_code.encode())

        return struct.pack("<I16sII40s", sendCode.constructor, phone_number_io.getvalue(), self.sms_type, self.api_id, params_io.getvalue())


class MTProto(MTProtoParent):
    def __init__(self, api_secret, api_id):
        MTProtoParent.__init__(self, api_secret, api_id)

    def get_encrypted_message(self, message_data, debug=False):
        salt = self.dc.server_salt
        session_id = os.urandom(8)
        message_id = self.dc.generate_message_id()
        seq_no = self.dc.number
        payload = message_data
        to_be_encrypted = struct.pack('<8s8sQHI', salt, session_id, message_id, seq_no, len(payload)) + payload
        to_be_encrypted_padded = to_be_encrypted + os.urandom(-len(to_be_encrypted) % 16)

        if debug:
            print("\nin get encrypted message")
            print("\nto be encrypted data:")
            hexdump(to_be_encrypted_padded)

        msg_key = SHA.new(to_be_encrypted_padded).digest()[-16:]
        auth_key_id = self.dc.auth_key_id
        auth_key = self.dc.auth_key

        # to get 256bit AES Key and AES IV
        sha1_a = SHA.new(msg_key + auth_key[0:32]).digest()
        sha1_b = SHA.new(auth_key[32:48] + msg_key + auth_key[48:64]).digest()
        sha1_c = SHA.new(auth_key[64:96] + msg_key).digest()
        sha1_d = SHA.new(msg_key + auth_key[96:128]).digest()
        aes_key = sha1_a[0:8] + sha1_b[8:20] + sha1_c[4:16]
        aes_iv = sha1_a[8:20] + sha1_b[0:8] + sha1_c[16:20] + sha1_d[0:8]

        # generate encrypted data
        encrypted_data = crypt.ige_encrypt(to_be_encrypted_padded, aes_key, aes_iv)

        message = struct.pack('<8s16s', auth_key_id, msg_key) + encrypted_data

        if debug:
            print("\nencrypted data:")
            hexdump(message)
        return message

    def send_encrypted(self, message_data, debug=False):
        message = self.get_encrypted_message(message_data, debug=False)

        # message = struct.pack('<II', len(message) + 12, self.dc.number) + message
        message = struct.pack('<II', len(message) + 12, self.dc.number) + message
        msg_chksum = crc32(message)
        message += struct.pack('<I', msg_chksum)

        if debug:
            hexdump(message)

        self.dc.sock.send(message)
        self.dc.number += 1

        # self.dc.send_message(message)

    def checkPhone(self, phone_number):
        bytes_io = BytesIO()
        rpc.serialize_string(bytes_io, phone_number)
        query = rpc.checkPhone(bytes_io.getvalue()).get_bytes()
        # hexdump(query)
        self.send_encrypted(query, debug=True)
        # self.dc.send_message(query)
        print(rpc.checkedPhone().set_params(self.dc.recv_message()))

    def sendCode(self, phone_number, sms_type, lang_code):
        query = sendCode(phone_number, sms_type, self.api_id, self.api_secret, lang_code).get_bytes()
        # hexdump(query)
        self.send_encrypted(query, debug=True)
        # self.dc.send_message(query)
        self.dc.recv_message(debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mtp = MTProto("api_secret", "api_key")
    mtp.dc.create_auth_key()
    mtp.checkPhone(b"821011112222")
```

and server always responds as below, regardless what auth_key_id is,

```
00000000: 10 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  6C FE FF FF EE 28 CE 89
```

what is wrong with my code?